# Initialize a NSString member variable inside the view controller

Tags: iphone

I have a NSString member variable declared in the header file of the view controller:

```
@interface MyApprViewController : UIViewController {
 NSString *var;
        ... 
}

@property (retain) NSString *var;
...

-(IBAction)buttonPressed: (id)sender;
```

Inside the implementation, I use `@synthesize var` and try to use that var from within the implementation of the buttonPressed method, but it does not work properly and I assume it is because var was never initialized. Where can I initialize this variable? I do not want to do it inside the method; I want to do it once of course, because I will keep appending text to it:

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed: (id)sender {
 NSString *input = ((UIButton *)sender).currentTitle;
 var = [var stringByAppendingString:input];
 textField.text = var;  
 }

 [input release];
}
```

I tried overriding the init method inside the view controller class, but it never gets called (maybe because there is no explicit initialization of the view controller class?) So, where should I initialize `var` so that I can use it inside the view controller class (inside the buttonPressed method)?

Thanks,
Mihai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several places to initialize:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundle
```

This is the designated initializer. You said you overloaded "init" which is not the designated initializer for UIViewController.

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
```

If your view controller is itself inside of a parent NIB, this method is called once the parent NIB is fully loaded and the parent NIB's outlets have all been wired.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
```

If your view controller has a NIB, this is called when its NIB has been loaded.

```
- (void)loadView
```

If your view controller doesn't have a NIB, this is called when its view is first requested.

Comment: Thank for that. I used viewDidLoad and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The best place would be inside your `viewDidLoad` or any `init` method you use. If you have neither, just add a method `-(void)viewDidLoad` to your UIViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Of course this will not work, stringByAppendingString is an instance method, and var is never allocated. The best way to initialize ,if you have a nib file (as this example appera to have) is on viewDidLoad, but check before initialize if is allready nil, to avoid every time this method is called a new object is allocated. finally remember release

Comment: @user652716 - no signatures please; use your [profile page](http://stackoverflow.com/users/652716/user652716); see [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)